# React : Passing and retrieving data between parent and child using props and callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-props, react-component

I have a little problem, I know that I can use props to send data to my children, and callbacks to get data to my parents.

```
    function App() {

  return (
  
  <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

        
        <Test name="My Button" hit={replace}/>

        <Input bringText={}/>

        <Spot replacement=""/>

      
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}
```

A father and three children. A button child with a callback as a prop. An input child, and a text child.

What I want to do: When I click the button, and take the input in the other component, and put it in the text component.

I used a callback to come back to the father component, but now I don't know what to do.

Comment: You could use the React `context` api to make things available all through components

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You have a react component that has three child-components: a text-input component, a button component, and a text-output component.

---

## Solution

You need state. You can do that by creating a React.Component subclass or using a [State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) - if using React 16.8+.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // thanks dude!
    // creating our state, the output text is initially empty
    this.state = {output: ""}
  }
  render() {
    const { output } = this.state; // extracting our state, just output
    const input = React.createRef() // creating a reference for our input
    return (
      <div ref={output} >
        {/* INPUT COMPONENT */}
        <input ref={input}/>
        
        {/* BUTTON COMPONENT */}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({output: input.current.value})}> 
          Button 
        </button>
        
        {/* OUTPUT LABEL COMPONENT */}
        <h1> { output } </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

---

## Further Suggestions

- You should read up on states and read through the [react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) - it's actually really helpful
- Once you understand state and react syntax you should learn about [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) which will help retrieve information from child components without the clunky-ness of creating a state for your child component and setting it on callback.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Mammal!
You're on the right track. But, I'd suggest you go through the [react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) and the documentation about different [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Logically speaking, you have three requirements:

1. You'd want the parent to be able to get notified by the 'button' child,
2. Read the value in the 'input' child, and
3. Update the 'text' child with that value.

In the React world, you can do this in the following manner:

1. Provide a callback method as props to the button child.
2. Keep a reference (or `ref`) to the input child so that the parent can read the value in it later.
3. Use a react `state` to update the text child with the value of the input child every time the button is clicked.

Given below is a working example. The code is pretty self-explanatory imo. But, leave a comment if there's anything you don't understand.

```js
const MyText = ({labelText}) => 
  (<p>You entered {labelText}</p>);
const MyInput = ({reference}) => 
  (<input type="text" ref={reference} />);
const MyButton = ({handleClick}) => 
  (<button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>);

function Hello() {
  const [label, setLabel] = React.useState('');
  const inputField = React.useRef(null);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setLabel(inputField.current.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyInput reference={inputField} />
      <MyButton handleClick={handleClick} /> 
      <MyText labelText={label} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3vo65ZXn5pfsCfGM5H55X+SmwJHBlyNHPwRmWAPgJnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-qVsF1ftL3vUq8RFOLwPnKimXOLo72xguDliIxeffHRc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```